# Какой дистрибутив Linux выбрать для разработки?

Tags: linux

Какой дистрибутив вы бы посоветовали? Какой наиболее выделяется из серой массы остальных?
Пока смотрю в сторону:

```
Linux Mint 11
Ubuntu 10.11
Debian
Fedora
Red Hat
```

Comment: Из этих все три. Нормального верного ответа на такой вопрос нет. Только не очень понятно, почему убунту - 10.11, а не 12.04. Это вопрос скорее для обсуждения.

Comment: Ну это всего лишь мое мнение. Если вы предложите свою сборку линукса, я только "за". Только не забудьте объяснить почему.

Comment: Причём тут своя сборка)

Comment: выбирайте дистрибутив который знает ваш знакомый

Comment: Разработка под что имеется ввиду? Если С/С++ это будет один выбор, а если под Java другой, под web третий

Comment: @Barmaley, а чем отличается RH от Debian в разработке на C++/Java/Web?

Comment: Согласиться с @rnd_d можно, но такие знакомые должны **действительно глубоко** разбираться в системах.

Comment: вопрос не имеет смысла. Во всех дистрибутивах идёт стандартный gcc. jvm тоже для всех едина. Если брать среду разработки - то я собственнолично проверял работу QT Creator, Eclipse и IntelliJ Idea на Ubuntu 11.04. Результат превосходный. Хотя думаю и в остальных системах будут работать стабильно

Comment: У меня Fedora Раньше была Ubuntu10.10 и то и то удобно для моего уровня

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Debian, Ubuntu, Mint почти одинаковые, т.к. все построены на базе Debian'а и deb-based.
Тоже самое и с Fedora/RedHat - основаны на RedHat и rpm-based.

Не поленитесь, потратьте один-два дня, поставьте перед собой какую-нибудь задачу и решите ее в каждом из дистрибутивов. Вы увидите что решения однаковые, но зато сможете выбрать тот который больше по душе (GUI, локализация, плюхи для настройки и т.п.).

Я пользуюсь Debian'ом, но новичкам советую Ubuntu или Mint, т.к. в них больше удобных средств с GUI для настройки системы.

Comment: Большое спасибо за мудрое высказывание)

---
Дело в том, что большинством из перечисленных дистрибутивов пользовался, но надо было узнать лучший. Спасибо.

Comment: Лучший - это субъективное понятие. На вкус и цвет, как говорится.  Я точно могу сказать что *n?x лучше чем MS Windows для разработки, но не смею утверждать, что Debian лучше чем RedHat.

Comment: Спасибо вам .

Comment: @1101_debian Сумеете обосновать "лучшесть" `*nix'a` для разработки? :)

Comment: @Котик, Let's HolyWar begin? =)

Как минимум удобнее настраивать окружение для разработки (IDE, системы контроля версий, сторонние библиотеки и т.п.). И конечно же терминал :)

PowerShell не в счет, когда я уже был влюблен в bash, его еще не было =)

Comment: @Котик Берём аргумент П. Грэма для языков программирования. *nix'ы (будем рассматривать уже -- фрюниксы) люди делали для себя, инструменты от MS -- это инструменты от MS для каких-то пользователей.

Comment: Я и сам люблю покодить под убунтой, но рассматривать ее как основную ОС для разработки пока не могу. Большей частью, видимо, из-за `Visual Studio`.

@1101_debian

- Что мешает настроить окружение под `Win`?
- Сейчас все распространенные `IDE` сильно двигаются в сторону идеологии `"IDE is a full source control provider",` поэтому, как мне кажется, людей, читающих `diff'ы` в `git'`овской консоли должно становиться все меньше и меньше.
- `PowerShell` - торт :)

Comment: @alexlz

- Странный аргумент. Если инструмент от `XYZ` не удовлетворяет разработчиков, то его просто вытолкнут с рынка те, кто сделает то же самое более качественно или концептуально. А наличие олдскульных `geeks for geeks` утилит на процесс разработки влияет слабо, да и `cygwin` еще никто не отменял.

Comment: @Котик, я не знаю в винде добротных менеджеров пакетов, которые могут отправить меня пить чай пока выполняют всю рутину за меня =)

Comment: @1101_debian Да, тут сложно поспорить -  наблюдать за тем, как работает aptitude можно бесконечно :) Жалко, что издержки лицензий и особенностей установки под `win` дают о себе знать.

Comment: @Котик, разумеется, что все зависит от профиля разработки. Для .NET разработчика, естественно, винда будет удобнее. Для WPF разработчика альтернатив просто нету. А вот, к примеру, для веб-разработчиков на python/ruby/node.js linux явно предпочтительнее:

 * В винде нет нормальной консоли. Покажите мне что-нибудь хоть наполовину такоеже удобное как yakuake. PowerShell же торт только для дотнетчиков. 
 * Вы пробовали ставить консольный git под виндой? Этот тот еще секс.
 * Как сказали выше, пакетный менеджер. В linux любой пакет устанавливается одной командой `emerge/apt-get/yum имя_пакета`

Comment: * nginx/apache/node.js - все это работает в винде нестабильно, да и управлять неудобно.
 * Нет полноценных GNU утилит. Как прокинуть порт на внешний сервер? Как запустить комманду с таймаутом на выполнение? Как добавить задачу в крон? Как дампнуть заголовки идущие к серверу? Что, качать для каждой задачи утилиту? cygwin/mingw в большинстве случаев не помощники.
 * Сборка софта. Для примера, установить сторонние модули для nginx можно только при пересборке, при этом сборка nginx не работакт по cygwin.

Comment: > Жалко, что издержки лицензий и особенностей установки под win дают о себе знать.

Кстати, Gentoo лишен этой проблемы. В portage можно [глобально принять любые лицензии](http://en.gentoo-wiki.com/wiki/Licenses), а в случае если дистрибутив нельзя скачать по прямой ссылке, то portage просто выдает инструкцию по какой ссылке скачать файл.

К примеру, Sun JDK в Gentoo ставится так же просто, как и любой другой пакет, в отличии от debian based дистрибутивов.

Comment: @Котик. msys, cygwin... Заменитель -- он и в Африке заменитель. Вместо того, чтобы просто что-то сделать, частенько приходится извращаться. А что касается Visual Studio -- так это к Петцольду. Он в статье (уже старой, 2005 или 2008 года) её посчитал неизбежной, но дурно влияющей на мозги. А лучшего популяризатора программирования под винды вроде и нету.

Comment: Народ, есть же виртуальные машины. Ставите linux как основную, вин как виртуалку. Вин юзаете для вижуал студио, лин для остального

Answer (score 7):

Лично я пользуюсь [`Gentoo`](http://www.gentoo.org/). И считаю, что вряд-ли кто-нибудь лучше разработчиков способен оценить пользу от контроля зависимости пакетов и гарантии совместимости библиотек благодаря сборки из исходников. Однако `Gentoo` требует определённых навыков работы в *nix и рассчитан, скорее, на power users. Начинающим линуксоидам придётся потратить время на изучение всей подноготной Linux, но это с лихвой окупится.

Из более простых бинарных дистрибутивов я бы посоветовал [`Debian squeeze`](http://www.debian.org/releases/stable/) — стабильный как скала. Но за стабильность придется платить, отставание пакетов очень сильное. К примеру, [`Chromium`](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/chromium-browser) там до сих пор шестой версии. Если не хочется сидеть со старым софтом, то можно поставить ветку [wheezy](http://www.debian.org/releases/testing/), но про стабильность тогда можно забыть.

`Ubuntu` я бы не стал советовать. На мой взгляд, по большей части, этот дистрибутив отличается от нестабильной ветки `Debian` лишь самописным [DE](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0) да кучей фич. По моему мнению, этот попсовый дистрибутив больше подходит для "домохозяек" и тех, кто впервые знакомится с Линуксом.

Comment: домохозяйствую несколько лет на ubuntu. Мне постояно хочется свежего софта и библиотек, незнаю сколько бы лет я ждал компиляции из исходников всего того что я ставлю и обновляю. Очень много репозиториев со всем чем только душа пожелает. Ну а de можно и поменять.

Comment: Как я и сказал: Debian wheezy вид сбоку

> незнаю сколько бы лет я ждал компиляции из исходников

Популярный аргумент тех, среди тех, кто Gentoo/Arch в глаза не видел :)

Comment: @Ilya Pirogov, если можно поподробнее о *само* и *несамо* -писном DE (Desctop Environment ?) и как это на самостоятельную разработку влияет ?

Естественно, речь не идет о разработке данной DE.

Comment: > если можно поподробнее о само и несамо -писном DE (Desctop Environment ?) 

Я имел ввиду их фирменную [Unity](http://unity.ubuntu.com/).

> и как это на самостоятельную разработку влияет ?

В том-то и дело, что никак не влияет. 

Удобная она или нет - не имеет значения, поскольку это всего-лишь DE, который можно поменять в любой момент. А других значимых отличий от Debian wheezy я не смог найти.

Comment: Да, в Unity я не въехал. Часок потыркался и все снес.

Comment: @avp - ну так для oldschool ребят есть-же *gnome classic*. Хотя по сравнению с форточками, как по мне, даже Unity  рулит. Лично я юзаю третий gnome shell.

Очень много все пишут о стабильности, но здесь же речь идет не о сервере.

@Ilya Pirogov - по тем параметрам, которые вы описали выше в комментариях подходит любой nix :)

Вообще солидарен с @avp - большой разницы действительно нет, а вот если уже вести речь о серверах - тогда да, холиварчиГ еще тот получился-бы

Оффтоп: Поражаюсь тем, кто с пеной у рта доказывает что Debian лучше, сложнее, круче etc. чем бубунта

Comment: да кучей **свистоперделок**... разве это плохо? ^_^

Comment: Вы невнимательно прочитали пост, я не утверждал, что Debian круче и сложнее. Я лишь сказал, что не вижу ни одного существенного отличия Ubuntu от Debian wheezy. Вы можете назвать хоть одно такое отличие?

> да кучей свистоперделок... разве это плохо? ^_^

Вероятно, хорошо, поскольку популяризирует дистрибутив и линукс в целом. Но что в этом хорошего для *разработчика*?

Comment: @Ilya Pirogov - я внимательно читал пост, я не о вас, я имел введу вообще. А что плохого? В вашем посте это преподноситься так, как будто-бы это плохо.

И как я уже писал выше - речь не о сервере, а о машине для разработки, вас же ответ больше подходит для вопроса - какой nix дистрибутив выбрать для сервера.

Ну тот-же Debian squeeze, да, для сервера самое то, но простите - что хорошего в нем для разработчика (вернее что лучше практически любого другого линукс дистрибутива)?

Вообще - на вкус и цвет, с этим спорить бесполезно...

Comment: > сколько бы лет я ждал компиляции из исходников

Это - BSD-way, а не Linux-way. В линуксе надо получать софт из менеджера пакетов, а не собирать самому из портов.

Comment: > На мой взгляд, по большей части, этот дистрибутив отличается от нестабильной ветки Debian'а лишь самописным DE да кучей свистоперделок. По моему мнению, этот попсовый дистрибутив больше подходит для "домохозяек" и тех, кто впервые знакомиться с линуксом.

Именно. Эта самая массовая аудитория и является целевой для космонавта в силу надежд на дальнейшую монетизацию. Unity и Gnome 3 - ошибочные ветви экспериментов над User Experience. И судя по недавним интервью господина Торвальдса, я не один так считаю. А KDE в Ubuntu готовить не умеют.

Comment: KDE, по-моему, нигде нормально готовить не умеют. Хоть SUSE и считается "кедовым" дистрибутивом, но с уже достаточно давних пор мне было удобно сидеть под гномом, пока не появился Gnome 3. Мне лично он кажется ужасным.

Comment: Кстати, Хешкод работает на этой самой "свистоперделке".

Comment: @mikillskegg, в смысле разработчики Хешкода Unity используют? Или вы о чем?

Comment: > Популярный "аргумент" среди тех, кто Gentoo в глаза не видел :)

Вы правы, мне стоит ее поставить.

Comment: @Ilya Pirogov, mission completed. Gentoo'шникCount++ xD

Answer (score 4):

[@WILD_BEAST](/users/7771/wild_beast), я тоже недавно выбирал. Так и не понял, как надо это  правильно делать.

Остановился на Ubuntu 10.04 дома и Xubuntu (сейчас 12.04 lts) на работе. Обе на виртуалке VirtualBox под Windows. Мне показалось, что в сети больше информации по ним, а не по RedHat (CentOS).

Обе выбрал lts, чтобы подольше не думать о переходе на новые версии. Пробовал Ubuntu 11.10 - интерфейс (Unity) решительно не понравился, с переделкой под Gnome решил не возиться.

Вообще, внешний вид Xfce в Xubuntu мне понравился больше. С другой стороны, я работаю в emacs и GUI мало использую.

До этого пользовал на работе RedHat (на серверах).

В принципе, процесс установки пакетов в Ubuntu/Xubuntu (apt-get) мне понравился больше. 
Что касается непосредственно разработки, то emacs, make, gcc, gdb, bash и т.д. всюду одинаковые. И sudo с ssh тоже работают.

Вы, извините за длинный и бестолковый ответ, т.к. краткое резюме - *существенной разницы нет*.

Comment: С таким набором требований всё что угодно подойдет :) Я бы в таких условиях выбирал то, что полегче, тем более в виртуалке гонять.

Comment: @northerner, немного уточню, что виртуалка в т.ч. для легкого изменения конфигурации машины (количество CPU, RAM, сеть виртуалок). 

Только проецировать результаты тестов на реальное железо надо с большой осторожностью.

Answer (score 1):

Выбирай любой, все равно через месяц любопытство узнать что же такого в другом дистрибутиве пересилит, и ты его попробуешь.

Answer (score 1):

А я сижу на OpenSUSE. И мне нравится этот дистрибутив больше, чем всякие Убунты. Вообще нужно самому попробовать и решить. Везде есть свои плюсы и минусы и особенности. С чем-то можно мириться, с чем-то нет. В целом же все дистрибутивы более-менее одинаковы.

Comment: Поддерживаю безусловно. По сравнению с Ubuntu две особенности выгодно отличают openSUSE:

- на этапе установки имеется гораздо больше возможностей по конфигурированию, в частности, выбору программного обеспечения; можно согласиться с базовым набором и фактически получить Ubuntu (там тоже компиляторы по дефолту не ставятся), можно выбрать нужные шаблоны (хочу, например, весь KDE, C/C++ разработку, LAMP, интергрированные среды), можно работать с отдельными пакетами;
- гениальная панель управления с графическим интерфейсом Yast - в Ubuntu почти всё в итоге приходится делать руками.

Comment: Да, YaST - хорошая штука. Очень нравится. А вообще изначально создатели OpenSUSE - немцы, а они отличаются особенной аккуратностью и педантичностью.

Answer (score 0):

используй Ubuntu

Comment: Почему вы так думаете?

Comment: ubuntu использует больше людей. если бы знали линукс лучше, не выбирали бы. а если не знать - лучше выбрать более используемый, а уже потом пересесть на другой если захочется

Comment: @mixalef, сколько из них - разработчики? Или потом спрашивать у домохозяек и школьников, как поставить самописного демона под управление systemd?

Comment: сколько из них НЕ разработчики? дай автору познакомиться с линуксом! потом я уверен он уже сам будет пробовать остальные версии. а спросить про линукс он и здесь сможет

Answer (score 0):

Тот, в котором удобнее работать.

Comment: Похоже на цитирование Записок Кэпа, но с другой стороны - какой вопрос, такой и ответ)

Comment: @mikillskegg, и в каком Вам удобнее ?

Comment: Xubuntu. Но для другого может быть по-иному. Хотя новичку я бы посоветовал именно ее.

Answer (score 0):

Для разработки бери с развитыми графическими средствами и KDE чтобы не тащить потом отдельно qt

Answer (score -1):

Расскажу свой путь - я начал устанавливать в виртуальной машине разные дистрибутивы. Начал читать статьи. Очень помог ресурс https://wiki.archlinux.org/ . Мой выбор остановился на Xubuntu. Debian показался слишком древним, Ubuntu(Unity/Gnome3) тормозил в ВМ, а в Mint под Mate не смог разобраться, почему небыло значка раскладки клавиатуры. Знаний установить Arch не хватило. В будущем, когда подучусь, есть планы попробовать Gentoo, Arch и Slackware.
Ubuntu с XFCE меня полностью удовлетворяют пока. В качестве обучения во второй ВМ у меня Debian(Squeeze) с Xmonad.

Comment: "в Mint под Mate не смог разобраться, почему небыло значка раскладки клавиатуры", не удивительно что linux у вас стоит виртуалкой :)

Comment: @AlexWindHope на сколько я понял, эту часть на Маte пока не спортировали. Или там был баг. Разбираться в сообществе и писать багрепорт мне было лень) факт оставался фактом - язык клавиатуры не показывался. И я пошел самым простым путем - попробовал еще один дистрибутив)) пока не могу съехать из-за фотошопа и корела. Осваиваю гимп

Comment: GIMP становится тортиком, надо еще чуть-чуть подождать. В 2.8 уже появилась группировка слоев и для фанатов фотошопа однооконный режим. В 2.10 будет поддержка цвета с > 8 бит на канал и эффекты слоя. И всё, фотошоп, давай, до свидания.

А что в кореле есть по сравнению с инкскейпом? Я довольно поверхностно разбираюсь в векторной графике, но схемы рисовать и обводить сканы карт хватало :) Инкскейп, конечно, тормозноват пока что.

Answer (score -1):

Debian нужно сначала довести для себя прежде чем начать с ним работать уж очень многое нужно доустановить

Comment: Да ладно, уж очень многое это что?

Comment: Дебиан просто не подходил для использования на моем типе устройств - ноутбук,
пришлось настраиват вручную usb 3g modem, wi-fi,bluetooth

Comment: Это в каком году было-то? Проблемы были с Lenny, но это было очень давно.

Comment: да возможно с прошлого выпуска многое изменилос, сейчас пользуюсь mint 12   всем доволен